# What is the best way to add customized button and link it to C# code in sharepoint designer 2007

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to create a customized button in sharepoint designer 2007. What is the best way to do this? Using toolbox? or create a web part? And how to link the button I created to a piece of C# code. I am quite new to the sharepoint development. Hope any one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't easily add c# code through designer. You'll need to create a web part. If you must add c# code in-line on the page you'll need to modify the web.config to allow in-line code. This isn't really recommended though. The best approach would be to create a web part. Also depends on what you want to do - could be solved in another way - html & javascript/jQuery?

Comment: If I want to implement a webpart that enables user to copy and paste a group of files from a file list. Do you think it is possible to do it in html&javascript/jQuert through sharepoint designer 2007? thanks